# Express-session is getting wiped by react router link

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, react-router

I have a game and it store all users data in Session body on Node Server. (To make it unique per player).

But when i am using react-router (Basic routing to another page) my session is getting wiped.

Does anyone know how i can keep session while routing from page to page.?

I attached the github repo with Server code and React code below.

[This is GitHub repo with session problem](https://github.com/afiliptsov/hangman-game)

I tried to google what is the solution but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy was not set up on project.
My endpoints were **pointing to localhost instead of having a proxy in "package.json".**

Example of proxy:  **"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"**

Than when you do endpoints in react instead of 'http://localhost/:3001/api/letter', you should use **'/api/letter'**.